# Polynomial Expansions using Taylor series

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

I'm trying to find the 15th term's coefficient in the following equation.

$$\frac{\left(1-x^6\right)^4}{(1-x)^4}$$

What I do is segregate each term as follows respectively.

$$\left(1-x^6\right)^4 \\ \text{and} \\ \frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$$

I think the multiplication of coefficients of $x^{12}$ and $x^{3}$ is the adequate way to obtain the coefficient of $x^{15}$.

$$\left(1-x^6\right)^4 = x^{24}-4 x^{18}\color{blue}{+6 x^{12}}-4 x^6+1$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = 1+4 x+10 x^2\color{blue}{+20 x^3}+35 x^4+56 x^5+... $$

It yields $\color{blue}{120 x^{15}}$. However, I get the following when I put the first composite expression to obtain its Taylor series.

$$\frac{\left(1-x^6\right)^4}{(1-x)^4} = \frac{O}{x^6}+x^{20}+4 x^{19}+10 x^{18}+20 x^{17}+35 x^{16}\color{purple}{+56 x^{15}}+80 x^{14}+104 x^{13}+125 x^{12}+140 x^{11}+146 x^{10}+140 x^9+125 x^8+104 x^7+80 x^6+56 x^5+35 x^4+20 x^3+10 x^2+4 x+1$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are you looking for the expansion around $\infty$?

Comment: @SineoftheTime, I'm sorry for my being low-level, but is there any other opportunity for expansion other than $∞$? I just tried to obtain $x^{15}$'s coefficient.

Comment: It seems that you expanded $\frac1{(1-x)^4}$ around $0$

Comment: @SineoftheTime I've applied the shadowed formulas here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJNQU.png

Comment: I've no doubt, but the last expression is the expansion around $\infty$, not around $0$

Comment: @SineoftheTime, does it matter concerning coefficients?

Comment: I'm writing an answer

Comment: @SineoftheTime Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems: the first one is that the last line you wrote represents the expansion around $\infty$ and not around $0$. Moreover, to get the coefficient of $x^{15}$, you have to consider the coefficients of: $x^{12}$ and $x^3$, $x^6$ and $x^9$, $x^{15}$ and $x^0$. The correct answer is the following:
$$(1-x^6)^4 = x^{24}-4 x^{18}+\color{blue}6 x^{12}-\color{orange}4 x^6+\color{red}1\\ 
\frac1{(1-x)^4}=1+4x+\dots+\color{blue}{20}x^3+\dots+\color{orange}{220}x^9+\dots+\color{red}{816}x^{15}+\dots
$$
The coefficient of $x^{15}$ is:
$$6\cdot20+ 220\cdot(-4)+816\cdot 1=56$$
and it matches with the [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C6%5D%5C%2841%29%2C4%5D%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%291-x%5C%2841%29%2C4%5D%5D+expansion) around $x=0$.

Comment: Whoaa! Gotcha! You caught it! Thank you.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire You're welcome, hope it's clear now